# Django model - select related count

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model, and I need to find out how many OtherModel instances are pointing to the same MyModel instance.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    int = models.SmallIntegerField()

class OtherModel(models.Model):
    other_model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, null=True, blank=True)
    int = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

I can use a for-loop, but the performance is very bad. Is there any other way I can select all MyModel objects, and get the related count in one query?

```
for m in MyModel.objects.all(): 
       count = self.othermodel_set.count()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count

result = MyModel.objects.all().annotate(othermodel_count=Count('othermodel'))
```

Django doc about [aggregation features](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/).